# Filename scanning for certain names Python

Tags: python

I have lots of files in a directory, lets say around 100, most of their file names begin with "Mod", i need to add all filenames that begin with "Mod" to a list so i can reference them later in my code. Any help? Thanks!

Comment: i tried using an if "mod" in , but it turns out it was just searching for a list called mod!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [glob](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html) package.

```
import glob

filepaths = glob.glob('/path/to/file/Mod*')
```

More generally, you can use [`os.listdir`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.listdir).  Unlike `glob`, it only returns the last part of the filename (without the full path).

```
import os

directory = '/path/to/directory'
filenames = os.listdir(directory )

full_filepaths = [os.path.join(directory, f) for f in filenames]
only_files = [f for f in full_filepaths if os.path.isfile(f)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [glob](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html) library to find the files with the given pattern:

```
import glob,os
mylist=[]
os.chdir("/mydir")
for file in glob.glob("Mod*"):
        mylist.append(file)

print mylist
```

or you can use [os.walk](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk)

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('/mydir'):
    for names in files:
        if names.startswith("Mod"):
             mylist.append(os.path.join(root, names))
```